# Datasheet Cross Reference for Old Military Part?

Tags: identification, vintage

I am looking for a datasheet for a part labelled [0N088586](https://aerobasegroup.com/part-number/0N088586_00-927-3137), but have been unable to find a datasheet. Does anyone know if there is a way to cross-reference the NSN with an equivalent part?

- The part is an old "can" IC, and it appears to be some kind of logic circuit (see link)
- `98230` is printed above the 0N0 number, but I wasn't able to find anything related to it.
- The numbers `94 6 48` are etched across the top.

Comment: Is this for debug, repair or functional issues?  My guess is a dual high speed CMOS comparator or high speed  dual 2in NAND. *Output Logic Form Complementary-logic  Input Circuit Pattern Dual 2 input*

Comment: @Tony This is mainly curiosity. My grandpa was a technician for the USAF and he gave me a bunch of old components. I'm just trying to determine whether it is useful today and whether or not it still works.

Comment: The link you provide is of a company that provides equal or equivalent parts.  Seems reasonable that they should be able to provide the datasheet to you (although it might not be free).